# How to replace old Swagger with latest Swagger GUI using Swashbuckle in an exsisting project

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Currently have a project in which swagger is setup using swashbuckle in asp.net. I would like to incorporate the new Swagger UI https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/. Is there an easy way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use [Swagger-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/) (I'm the owner of that project) 
Swagger-Net is a fork of swashbuckle and we get the latest swagger-ui and other dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. Works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have swash-buckle installed in your project and are using default Swagger UI,

1. Uninstall the packages from your project.
2. Search for Swagger-Net in your nuget package manager and install it.
3. Replace all using swash-buckle statements with `Swagger.Net`.

You are good to go !!

[Github Wiki](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/wiki)